# Как из MongoDB средствами PHP взять не весь массив документа, а только первые его 10 элементов?

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$userDoc = $collection->findOne(array('userID' => $id));
//$userMas = $userDoc['userMas'];
$userMas10 = ?
```

Допустим у нас массив 1 миллион элементов, чтоб не забивать ресурсы нужно из базы взять не весь массив, а массив первых 10 элементов, чтоб 1 миллион не вытаскивался из базы.

Comment: У вас условие `findOne`, как может получаться массив из 1 миллиона элементов?

Comment: findOne находит документ по id, у этого документа есть поле-массив 'userMas' в 1 миллион элементов. Получается он вот так $userMas = $userDoc['userMas']; Только мне весь его получать не нужно, а только массив из его первых 10 элементов.

Comment: Отредактировал свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Можно это сделать следующим образом:

Mongo Shell:

```
> db.testdata.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583c12b16495812685144ed5"), "mas" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] }
> db.testdata.findOne( { "_id": ObjectId("583c12b16495812685144ed5") } , { mas: { $slice: 5 } } )
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583c12b16495812685144ed5"),
    "mas" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
    ]
}
```

В коде:

```
$userDoc = $collection->findOne(array('userID' => $id));
$userMas = $collection->findOne(array('userID' => $id), array('userMas' => array( '$slice' => 10 ) ));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Подправил свой вопрос.